# Are Calendars considered to be Azure AD based resources?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks#supported-resources states that Azure AD based resources are subject to a Per app and tenant combination: 7 total subscriptions

Calendars are assigned to users. Does this mean that they are "Azure AD based resources"?

I'm hoping to be able to have hundreds of subscriptions active for a single tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since the line reads:

> Certain limits apply to Azure AD based resources (users, groups) and may generate errors when exceeded:

I'd assume it only applies to users and groups which reside in Azure AD. Office 365 Calendars do not, MS Graph API gets them from the Outlook Calendars API.

And it's not too hard to test this, try creating 8 subscriptions :)

Comment: This is correct. "Azure AD based" here means stored in Azure AD. Calendars are stored in Exchange Online.